# OTB Pansharpening Error: Adapter for adaptPansharpening-bayes not found

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, pansharpening

When I try to use the OTB pansharpening tool inside the processing tool box I always get this message: "Adapter for adaptPansharpening-bayes not found". I guess it's an issue withe the configuration. Has anyone a solution for my problem?

Comment: Could you give more information about your installation (Version, OS...) ? Do you have similar problem with other tools ?

Comment: I'm working eith QGIS 2.6. I did the OTB-OSGEO4W installation. The processing configuration is this: OTB application folder (C:\OSGeo4W\apps\orfeotoolbox\applications) and OTB command line tools folder (C:\OSGeo4W\bin).

Comment: I forgot to say that I use windows 7.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your problem, but I have no time today. But is it specific to bayes pansharpening or do you have the problem with other parameters/other tools.

Comment: You would advise to open a bug on qgis bug tracker

Comment: I have the problem with all the other pansharpening tools.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with the installation. After reinstalling the OTB tool this problem is solved. Unfortunately, I got another problem. Here is the link to my new question:

[What causes OTB pansharpening ERROR Inputs do not occupy the same physical space?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126374/otb-pansharpening-doesnt-work)

Comment: Consider marking this question as accepted. Thanks.